# JPA is taking long time to respond

Tags: sql, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data, microservices

I am trying to fetch data from Tax table.The table is having 16 columns.We are trying to fetch all the columns using one of the indexed column:accountCode.
There is no join present in the query.Its a plain select that that is selecting 16 columns.
Here is the JPA Code:

```
@Repository
public interface TaxRepository extends JpaRepository<TaxData,String>,QueryByExample<TaxData>{
}

//Method that is fetching data from Database:

List<TaxData> taxDataInfo=new ArrayList();
TaxData data=new TaxData();
data.accountCode("abc");

**This below code is taking  13 minutes time to  give result.The record count:28858**

taxrepository.findAll(Example.of(data)).forEach(taxDataInfo::add)
```

Can some one please help here how can this performance issue be  addressed.How can we handle such large data in the application with better performance.I need all the records .Hence used findAll() and need to create the query with Dynamic parameters .Hence used QueryByExample API.

Comment: How many rows are in that table? How does the `TaxData` entity look like? What SQL statements get executed? How long does each need to execute? How many different `accountCode` values are in the table? How often is the `accountCode` `"abcd"`?

Comment: Please enable sql logging and check whatvisbthe sql.getting executed. Also consider @jens suggestion